# Rollup.js bundling images

Tags: reactjs, webpack, rollupjs

In webpack world I can bundle and access images as urls in the following way using [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader)

Like so:

```
const webpackConfig = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]'}
        ],
        include: paths
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And using it like this on a react component for example:

```
import foo from 'assets/images/foo.png'

function ReactFunctionalComponent () {
  return (<img src={foo} />)
}
```

That would put foo with the path of the image

Is there a way to do the same on rollup js so I can have an image asset as a URL with a hash inside the bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add functionality to rollup using plugins. 
In this case use `rollup-plugin-image` (https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-image) or `rollup-plugin-img` (https://github.com/alwaysonlinetxm/rollup-plugin-img) which seems to be more flexible.

Take into account this technique can increase the size of the file.

Comment: An important detail about this plugin:

`Images are encoded using base64, which means they will be 33% larger than the size on disk. You should therefore only use this for small images where the convenience of having them available on startup`

Comment: Totaly agree with @bhdrk is there an easy way to achieve webpacks functionality in rollup rather then just inline all the images into your code ?